# playframework flash scope and cookies, won't that end up on another page?

Tags: playframework

We are trying to have state be tab specific, but play is putting the state in a cookie from what I understand.  Does this mean, I can end up with the same problems I was having with old frameworks with a session(and not the concept of a conversation)??

I would prefer to allow a user to have two tabs open going through the process of buying a ticket so need to keep that data separate.  Is there an example for this in the playframework?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MY FINAL ANSWER AFTER RESEARCH that we went with.....I found out tab state can be stored in sessionStorage javascript object, IE8, IE9, firefox, chrome....If you want IE7, IE6, there is a google code project which can do this as well.....I now have tab state which is way better than seam conversations which end and begin when I don't want them too and throw all sorts of fun to debug exceptions....YEAH, off to the races now...I should accept this one as the best answer as this is a great way to go!!!

Answer (score 3):

If you're putting state into the ${session} or ${flash}-scopes, yes, they will be available on two browser tabs.

If you want them to be separate, you'd have to implement conversations and store the state of the various conversations on the server (e.g. in the cache). 
You have to implement this yourself, there's nothing built in for this in Play.

Answer (score 2):

Yellow Dean,

I imagine that your process has many steps ? If you want to have many process instances, then you need many distinct urls, or to store an unique key in a hidden input tag.

```
/book/123-super-concert/?instance-key=123456

<input type="hidden" name="instance-key" value="123456" />
```

But you'll need to store in your database some objects that aren't valids, untill the process is complete.

The way i'll do it is to use AJAX on the client-side to simulate multiple pages, and validation.